# How to copy eststo

Tags: copy, stata, estimation

How would I copy the the contents of `eststo` and create another `eststo`?

For example:

```
sysuse auto2, clear

eststo clear
eststo estimates1: reg price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn, robust
estadd local aa "abc"
estadd local bb "bcd"

esttab estimates1
```

What I want to do is to copy `estimates1` and create `estimates2`. The two should be identical.

Of course, one way to do this is to just re-run the regression again:

```
eststo clear
eststo estimates1: reg price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn, robust
    estadd scalar obs=e(N)
    estadd local aa "abc"
    estadd local bb "bcd"
eststo estimates2: reg price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn, robust
    estadd scalar obs=e(N)
    estadd local aa "abc"
    estadd local bb "bcd"   
esttab estimates1 estimates2, stats(obs aa bb)
```

But is there a way to do something like this (incorrect):

```
eststo estimates2 = estimates1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
eststo clear

eststo estimates1: reg price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn, robust

estadd scalar obs=e(N)
estadd local aa "abc"
estadd local bb "bcd"

eststo estimates2

esttab estimates1 estimates2, stats(obs aa bb)
```

Note that the following also works:

```
esttab estimates1 estimates1, stats(obs aa bb)
```

Both approaches will produce the desired output:

```
--------------------------------------------
                      (1)             (2)   
                    price           price   
--------------------------------------------
mpg                -104.5          -104.5   
                  (-1.21)         (-1.21)   

rep78               723.2*          723.2*  
                   (2.29)          (2.29)   

headroom           -656.0*         -656.0*  
                  (-2.23)         (-2.23)   

trunk               79.23           79.23   
                   (1.05)          (1.05)   

weight              5.286*          5.286*  
                   (2.66)          (2.66)   

length             -93.33          -93.33   
                  (-1.51)         (-1.51)   

turn               -196.6          -196.6   
                  (-1.24)         (-1.24)   

_cons             16142.5*        16142.5*  
                   (2.08)          (2.08)   
--------------------------------------------
obs                    69              69                                          
aa                    abc             abc   
bb                    bcd             bcd   
--------------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```